# Create dynamic graph in Excel via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to create a graph, manually or with VBA, which will automatically update when new sheets are added. Data is imported from an external table monthly, and each time is added to a new sheet. The data structure is the same every time.

I know how to use dynamic graphs if I want to have it update for new rows and columns, but this is different.

I tried using macro recorder along with the PivotChart Wizard, and then modifying it with a for loop, like this:

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= _
Array("Sheet" & i & "!R1C1:R10C7", "Item1"), _
Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:= _
"PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6

More Code

Next i
```

The rest of the code sets up a Sum of Values, and so on.

I see that there's a PivotCaches.Item method, but I don't see anything about updating an existing PivotChart.

This doesn't have to be a PivotChart, if a regular chart would work. Similarly, if there's a way to do it without VBA, that's also fine.

EDIT: I think I got it solved. Any critiques are welcome.

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
If IsEmpty(pivotArray) Then
    pivotArray = Array(1)
    ReDim Preserve pivotArray(1 To UBound(pivotArray) + 1) As Variant
    pivotArray(1) = Array("Sheet" & i & "!R1C1:R4C3", "Item1")
Else
    ReDim Preserve pivotArray(1 To UBound(pivotArray) + 1) As Variant
    pivotArray(UBound(pivotArray)) = Array("Sheet" & i & "!R1C1:R4C3", "Item1")
End If
Next i
```